# How to clarify "Predatory trading" process?

Tags: trading, liquidity

[Brunnermeier, 2005](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2005.00781.x)  studied the "predatory trading"

> This paper studies predatory trading, trading that induces and/or
> exploits the need of other investors to reduce their positions. **We
> show that if one trader needs to sell, others also sell and
> subsequently buy back the asset. This leads to price overshooting and
> a reduced liquidation value for the distressed trader**. Hence, the
> market is illiquid when liquidity is most needed. Further, a trader
> profits from triggering another trader's crisis, and the crisis can
> spill over across traders and across markets.

From reading the definition, I have some unclear points:

Regarding this part "**We show that if one trader needs to sell, others also sell and subsequently buy back the asset.**".

My understanding is that if one investor knows that another investor needs to sell, this investor will sell to reduce the price and then buy back the asset with the lower price.

And, what is unclear to me is how it leads to "**This leads to price overshooting and a reduced liquidation value for the distressed trader**". From my understanding, "price overshooting" means that "price drastically increase". But when an investor sells together like that, how come the price increase? Apart from that, "liquidation value" is the price of the asset. So in the same sentence, the author says that the asset price increase(price overshooting) or decrease (reduced liquidation value), which means I may fall into a fallacy of explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price overshooting doesn’t necessarily imply that the price is too high. It implies that if the price changes from one level to another level, the price first moves past the final level and then back to the final level.